# Permissions issues for shared directory on a server

Tags: linux, permissions, file-sharing

The setup is we have a VPS running Debian Squeeze, and I've set up a shared directory for us to share files.  So far I've followed this guide:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setup-shared-directory/

I've also set the umask to 002 correctly (see the comments on that guide), so we can both now create files and directories directly on the server and we both have read/write permissions on them.

The only problem is that a lot of our files are created on our local machines (both running Ubuntu 10.10), and then dumped on the server.  This results in only the creator of the file/directory having write permissions on, and the other member of the group I set up for sharing this folder only having read access.

My next thought would be to change the default umask on our local machines, but it seems a bit extreme to have to do that, and I don't know if it's a security risk.

Can someone tell me if there's a better solution to what I'm trying to achieve, or if this really is the way to go?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: How are the files `dumped` onto the server ? If using ftp which ftpd is running on the server ?

Comment: I'm using SFTP graphically through Nautilus on my Ubuntu desktop.  I assume that means the fact that I can transfer files to it using SFTP that the server is running this also, but I don't have too much experience with this, so if you mean something else then let me know.  Cheers.

Comment: @Jagot: can you run `ps aux | grep ftp` on your server and tell us which ftp daemon is running - it's likely vsftpd|proftpd.

Comment: @Iain: Here's the result of that command: '~$ ps aux | grep ftp
tom       3484  0.0  0.1   3300   748 pts/0    S+   13:10   0:00 grep ftp'

Comment: @Jagot:you will need to find out what ftp server is running on your remote system and let us know. You will most likely need to tweak the config to make it work correctly for you.

Comment: @Iain: I don't think there is an ftp server running - I haven't set one up - I'm just doing everything through ssh.  Is there any other way I can find out what's going on?

Comment: There is no FTP server.... SFTP uses ssh, not FTP.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a different approach and share the files through an [access control list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) on the directory.

First make sure access control lists are enabled on the filesystem where the directory resides (make sure that the corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab` contains `acl` in the fourth column). Also make sure you have the acl utilities installed (on Debian, install the `acl` package). Then give both users an inheritable write permission on the directory.

```
setfacl -m user:other_user:rwx /path/to/directory
setfacl -d -m user:other_user:rwx /path/to/directory
```

If there are more than two users, either repeat this command for each user (the ACL is implicit for the user who created the directory); or put the users in a group (as you already did), and use `-m group:group_name:rwx` in the `setfacl` command.

Comment: sorry it has taken me so long to reply to this as I have only just been able to implement this, but I'm still in the same situation of the files I dump in this directory that I have created on my local machine only have read/write permissions for me, and only read for the rest of the group.  I don't know if this is as a result of all the messing around I've done in this particular directory.  Still the only way I can get it to work is by setting the umask on my local machine 0002.  Files I create on the server itself are fine, but that's not the method we mainly use.

Comment: @Jagot: I think we need more information to help you then. Please edit your question to describe precisely how you upload files to the server, and show the output of `getfacl` on a file that doesn't have the desired permissions and the containing directories all the way up to the root of the shared space.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was being thick in the comments. the sftp-server is being run by root and you pick up root's umask. You should be able to fix this by editing your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and changing the line

`Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

to

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/sh -c `umask 0002; /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`
```

Comment: watch out for the smart-quotes in this answer! (did you copy-paste from this blog http://jeff.robbins.ws/articles/setting-the-umask-for-sftp-transactions ?  It seems to derive from this site's very own @Gilles :))

Comment: @simon: I think it came from the Ubuntu forums but it's been stuck in my tiddlywiki for a few months.

Comment: @simon: That was a different Gilles. I'd have recommended ACLs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Iain's answer, which should work (but watch out for the smart-quotes, and see below for a caveat), at the top of `/etc/init.d/ssh` you will find:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     sshd
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     
# Short-Description:    OpenBSD Secure Shell server
### END INIT INFO

...

umask 022
```

and you can change the value here.

**Caveat:**

many S/FTP clients will try to set the permissions on newly uploaded files to match the permissions on the local system, so check if this is what's happening.  If it is, you can usually disable this option in the settings of the client you're using to upload.

**edit:**

as another suggestion, when creating a set-up like this, I always make full use of the sticky-bit for group ownership (i.e., I set all directory permissions to 2775) so that newly created files and directories inherit the correct group ownership.